# If a group S has at least 7 elements of order 7, prove that S has at least 12 elements of order 7.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I think this involve's using LaGrange's Theorem, but I can't understand it. Initially, I thought each power of a 1 through n-1=6 will have an inverse of order 7, giving 12 with the 0-th power leftover. Any explanation appreciated! There's a similar thread to this, but can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem isn't all that helpful in this problem because Lagrange's theorem discusses the size of the whole group and doesn't focus on the number of elements of a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) Choose some element of order 7. What is the subgroup that it generates? 2) How many elements of order 7 does that subgroup account for?
3) What is the intersection of any two such subgroups?

Answer (score 1):

An element of order $7$ generates a subgroup of order $7$. This subgroup consists of the identity as well as $6$ elements of order $7$. Thus if the group has more than $6$, there must be two distinct subgroups of order $7$. Since any nonidentity element of a subgroup of order $7$ generates the whole group, the two distinct subgroups of order $7$ most intersect exactly in the identity. Thus the union of the two subgroups has $13$ elements; the identity, and $12$ elements of order $7$. This is what we wanted to show.